# Reading ionic www/config.xml file from device

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, ionic-framework

I am having trouble reading the www/config.xml file from Android device. I tried two different approaches. First, I tried using the $http service which was recommended in another thread to do. When that did not work I then tried to use the Cordova file plugin. The reason I am doing this is to try to get the version number from the www/config.xml file in the app.  Below are both approaches:

1) $http.get()

```
 url = 'file:///android_asset/www/config.xml'
 $http.get(url)
    .then ((data) ->
      versionNumber = data.data.match(/<widget\s.*?\sversion=['"]([^'"]+)['"]/)
      verNum = versionNumber[1]
    ), (err) ->
    # {"data": null, "status": 0, .....}
      alert JSON.stringify err
```

2)  Cordova file plugin

```
   if ionic.Platform.isAndroid()
    path = 'file:///android_asset/www/'
    file = 'config.xml'
    $cordovaFile.readAsText(path, file)
      .then ((data) ->
        alert JSON.stringify data
        return
      ), (error) ->
        # I alert { code: 5 } which is an ENCODING_ERR
        alert JSON.stringify error
```

Comment: have you tried `url = 'config.xml'`

Comment: Yes that was my first attempt. It did not work.

Comment: Next I would check to see if the file actual exists in the build. Take your APK/IPA file and change the extension to `.zip` and then browse through the contents to see if maybe ionic is removing that file when building the project.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look to the folder platforms/android and you can see that the file `'android_asset/www/config.xml'` don't exists. 
You could try reading the file `'/res/xml/config.xml'` or you could try a different approach for example creating a [Cordova Hook](https://github.com/apache/cordova-lib/blob/master/cordova-lib/templates/hooks-README.md).

> **Cordova Hooks**:
>
> Cordova Hooks represent special scripts which could be added by
>   application and plugin developers or even by your own build system to
>   customize cordova commands.

You could adapt the [replace text hook from this article](http://devgirl.org/2013/11/12/three-hooks-your-cordovaphonegap-project-needs/) or this [build number hook](https://gist.github.com/Evanion/be750c2445416dd4f91a) based on the same hook.

**UPDATE**

To get only the version number of your app you could use this plugin:

> **Cordova AppVersion plugin**
>
> Cordova plugin to return the version number of the current app
>
> https://github.com/whiteoctober/cordova-plugin-app-version

[Is available also with ngCordova](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/appVersion/)

Answer (score 2):

ngCordova has a great set of plugins when working with ionic. 
To get the app version use this one: http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/appVersion/

I wanted to display the version number in my splash screen, so I used their example and added an event:

Inside `$ionicPlatform.ready` callback:

```
$cordovaAppVersion.getVersionNumber().then(function (version) {
    $rootScope.$broadcast("appVersionResolved", { version: appVersion });
}
```

In the splash screen controller:

```
$rootScope.$on("appVersionResolved", function(event, args) {
    $scope.appVersion = args.version;
});
```

Comment: Very nice. May I ask where you have your `$ionicPlatform.ready` callback? Is that something you added or is it pre-existing in an Ionic app?

Comment: It's an ionic service: [link](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicPlatform/), 
and a bit more detailed: [link](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/utility/ionic.Platform/).
I pass it a callback function that starts my app initialization.