# Display version on screen from config.xml in Ionic2

Tags: ionic2

We are developing an app which has a screen named "About Us" where we want to display the app's version number which is same as in config.xml file.

```html
<widget id="com.myApp.MyAppName" version="2.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
```

Is there any way to copy the version no from the mentioned xml file to my screen's ts file or vice-versa?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading ionic www/config.xml file from device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28570152/reading-ionic-www-config-xml-file-from-device)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check this plugin out: http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/app-version/

Github link : https://github.com/whiteoctober/cordova-plugin-app-version

Let me know if this work out for you. Can help with specifics if needed.

Comment: Any idea how to do this in a PWA though?